# Custom UIView not displaying correctly inside EasyTipView

Tags: swift, uikit, tooltip

I'm pretty new to iOS swift programming. I'm trying to show a custom UIView inside a EasyTipView. But the custom view does not seem to be contained inside of the EasyTipView. Also, I'm using a view controller to manage the lifecycle of the the custom view. Can someone point me in the right direction.

I've removed all other text and button fields from the custom view to keep it simple for the sake of this issue.

EasyTipView is a Swift library to display tooltips.
Link: https://github.com/teodorpatras/EasyTipView

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

public class ToolTipTemplate: UIView {
    private let templateAttributes: TemplateAttributes
    private var toolTipView: EasyTipView? = nil
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    init(templateAttributes: TemplateAttributes) {
        self.templateAttributes = templateAttributes
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        layoutView()
    }
    
    func layoutView() {
        let content: Tooltip = Tooltip()
        content.configureValues(text: toolTipTemplateAttributes.byline)
        addSubview(content)
        content.useAutolayout()
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            content.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            content.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            content.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            content.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor),
            content.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    override public func didMoveToSuperview() {
        if superview != nil {
          // Do some business logic.
        }
    }

}

extension ToolTipTemplate {
    
    open class Tooltip: UIView {
        private let messageLabel = UILabel()
        private let contentStack = UIStackView()
        
        private var messageString: String? {
            didSet {
                guard oldValue != messageString else { return }
                guard let messageString = messageString,
                      messageString.isEmpty == false else {
                    messageLabel.isHidden = true
                    return
                }
                
                messageLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(
                    string: messageString,
                    style: .secondary,
                    alignment: .center,
                    foregroundColor: .color(.primary),
                    lineBreakMode: .byWordWrapping
                )
                
                            
            messageLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
            messageLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
                messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
                messageLabel.isHidden = false
                messageLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            }
        }
        
        public init() {
            super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
            setUpContent()
        }
        
        required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        
        public func configureValues(text: String? = nil) {
            messageString = text
            setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        }
        
      override public func updateConstraints() {
            setupConstraints()
            super.updateConstraints()
        }
        
        func setUpContent() {
            useAutolayout()
            messageLabel.useAutolayout()
            
            // Configure content stack
            contentStack.axis = .horizontal
            contentStack.spacing = 0.0
            contentStack.alignment = .center
            contentStack.distribution = .fill
            contentStack.useAutolayout()
            
            
            contentStack.addArrangedSubviews(messageLabel)
            contentStack.setCustomSpacing(.spacer(.small), after: messageLabel)
            
            messageLabel.isHidden = true
        }
        
        func setupConstraints() {

            removeAllSubviews()
            
            // Setup view
            addSubview(contentStack)
            messageLabel.textAlignment = .natural
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                // Content View
                contentStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
                messageLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentStack.topAnchor),
                messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentStack.leadingAnchor),
                messageLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentStack.trailingAnchor),
                
                contentStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
                contentStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

I have a view controller via which I'm trying to show the ToolTipTemplate UIView inside of an EasyTipView.

```swift
import Foundation

public class ToolTipViewController : UIViewController {

    private let TooltipMessageView: TooltipMessageView
    private let forView: UIView
    private let withinSuperview: UIView
    private var toolTipRef: EasyTipView? = nil

    init(tooltipMessageView: TooltipMessageView, forView: UIView, withinSuperview: UIView) {
        self.tooltipMessageView = tooltipMessageView
        self.forView = forView
        self.withinSuperview = withinSuperview
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        showTooltip()
        view = toolTipRef
    }

    func showTooltip() {
        guard let toolTip = tooltipMessageView.getView() as? ToolTipTemplate else {
            return
        }
        
        toolTipRef = EasyTipView.standard(contentView: toolTip, arrowPosition: .bottom, boundsSize: withinSuperview.bounds.size, dismissOnTap: false, delegate: self)
        toolTipRef?.show(forView: forView, withinSuperview: withinSuperview) {
            [weak self] (finished) in
            guard finished == true else { return }
            // Do some businee logic here
        }
    }
}

extension DynamicMessagingToolTipViewController: EasyTipViewDelegate {
    public func easyTipViewDidDismiss(_ tipView: AlcatrazUI.EasyTipView) {
        // Do some business logic here.
        toolTipRef = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue might be related to the sizing and positioning of your custom view within the EasyTipView. Let's make some adjustments to your code.

First, update the ToolTipTemplate class to handle its own sizing:

```
public class ToolTipTemplate: UIView {
    private let templateAttributes: TemplateAttributes
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    init(templateAttributes: TemplateAttributes) {
        self.templateAttributes = templateAttributes
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        layoutView()
    }
    
    func layoutView() {
        let content: Tooltip = Tooltip()
        content.configureValues(text: toolTipTemplateAttributes.byline)
        addSubview(content)
        content.useAutolayout()
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            content.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            content.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            content.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            content.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    override public func didMoveToSuperview() {
        if superview != nil {
          // Do some business logic.
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when creating the EasyTipView in your ToolTipViewController, make sure to use the correct sizing:

```
func showTooltip() {
    guard let toolTip = tooltipMessageView.getView() as? ToolTipTemplate else {
        return
    }
    
    let tipView = EasyTipView.standard(contentView: toolTip, arrowPosition: .bottom, boundsSize: toolTip.bounds.size, dismissOnTap: false, delegate: self)
    
    toolTipRef = tipView
    tipView.show(forView: forView, withinSuperview: withinSuperview) { [weak self] (finished) in
        guard finished == true else { return }
        // Do some business logic here
    }
}
```

By setting the boundsSize of the EasyTipView to the size of your custom view (ToolTipTemplate), you ensure that the tooltip is correctly sized and positioned.

Also, make sure to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false for your custom views and their subviews to ensure that Auto Layout constraints work as expected. You can do this in the useAutolayout() method or directly in the init methods of your custom views.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ehsanslipknot. Can you elaborate on "First, update the ToolTipTemplate class to handle its own sizing"

Comment: Do I need to override sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {} in the ToolTipTemplate ?

Comment: I was able to get it to working by overriding sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {} in the ToolTipTemplate. Also, I implemented what @ehsanslipknot recommended about the the sizing and positioning of the custom view. Will post a full answer just for reference for someone else who might be facing the same issue.